# On iOS app the hamburger icon is cropped by a couple of pixels at the top

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I'm on iOS 8.3 on an iPhone 5. The hamburger icon is slightly cropped as per attached screenshot.

[image: screenshot]
[image: zoomed in]

Comment: Once it has been seen, it cannot be unseen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  It was a 14pt tall PDF with 14.5pt of content.